# Trouble solving simple time independent heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am modeling the temperature distribution in two parallel one dimensional  rods, one end at 300 K, the other at 30 K for one rod, with the other having a zero dT/dX=0  condition on one end, 300 K at the other.  If I put a weak thermal conductor between the two lines, heat flows from one to the other along the length.  As I increase the coupling from line to line, we see the temperature distribution of the line with the zero flux condition approach the heat sunk line more and more closely.  However, when the coupling exceeds some value, 4.5 in my case, the solution fails. I am not sure how to diagnose this, and I need to be able to run the case where the coupling conductance is similar to the axial conductance, so the two conductors should have very similar profiles.  Any help is much appreciated.  Sorry for the poorly presented first version.

```
dielectricthickness = .011 25.4 ;
manganinwidth = 6.;
manganinthickness = 0.001 25.4;

copperwidth = .004 25.4;
copperthickness = .002 25.4;

\[Kappa][t_] = 5.4*10^\[Minus]3 t



dConductance[t_] = 
  2  2  \[Kappa][
    t] copperwidth 1./(dielectricthickness - copperthickness)/2;

sol = NDSolve[{D[ D[Tc[x], x], x]  - 
      0. dConductance[Tc[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, 
    D[Tg[x] D[Tg[x], x], x] + 
      0. dConductance[Tg[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, Tg[0] == 300, 
    Tg[1] == 30, Tc[0] == 300, Tc'[1] == 0.}, {Tc, Tg}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[{Tg[x], Tc[x]} /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]

sol = NDSolve[{D[ D[Tc[x], x], x]  - 
      1.0 dConductance[Tc[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, 
    D[Tg[x] D[Tg[x], x], x] + 
      1.0  dConductance[Tg[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, Tg[0] == 300, 
    Tg[1] == 30, Tc[0] == 300, Tc'[1] == 0.}, {Tc, Tg}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[{Tg[x], Tc[x]} /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]

sol = NDSolve[{D[ D[Tc[x], x], x]  - 
      4.5 dConductance[Tc[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, 
    D[Tg[x] D[Tg[x], x], x] + 
      4.5  dConductance[Tg[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, Tg[0] == 300, 
    Tg[1] == 30, Tc[0] == 300, Tc'[1] == 0.}, {Tc, Tg}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[{Tg[x], Tc[x]} /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]

sol = NDSolve[{D[ D[Tc[x], x], x]  - 
      5.  dConductance[Tc[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, 
    D[Tg[x] D[Tg[x], x], x] + 
      5.  dConductance[Tg[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, Tg[0] == 300, 
    Tg[1] == 30, Tc[0] == 300, Tc'[1] == 0.}, {Tc, Tg}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[{Tg[x], Tc[x]} /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Sorry, the image with the description of the problem and the error message did not make it into the post.  The error message I get is "NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.023954846157398547`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected."  The physical system should not have anything funny going on at this point.

Comment: You seem to be loading some packages local to your setup `cu20Int << cu20Int
manganinInt << manganinInt;` . This will make it hard to run your code. No? At least that is what `<<` is typically used for.

Comment: `cu20Int[x]` is undefined.

Comment: Am I the only on who managed to find zero information for the packages when googling `cu20Int mathematica` and likewise for the other one?

Comment: Sorry, they are interpolation functions. I will try to attach them.

Comment: How do I include the Interpolation functions?  Do I have to go back to the points I used to fit them, or is there a way to export them to you.

Comment: things seem to be working now better. can you please provide the values for `copperwidth` and `copperthickness`?

Comment: Sorry -  I fixed it.

Comment: @HM51 Function `\[Kappa][t]` is not defined. Do you try to compute parameter or function `\[Kappa][t]` to make temperature profiles similar?

Comment: Just using the \Kappa to keep track of a conductance in physical units.  Fixed it, and I hope there are no more.  Next time I will restart the kernel and test before posting.

Comment: Did you see the [HeatTransfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html) in the product?

Answer (score 2):

Solution with Mathematica FEM

```
dielectricthickness = .011 25.4 ;
manganinwidth = 6.;
manganinthickness = 0.001 25.4;

copperwidth = .004 25.4;
copperthickness = .002 25.4;

\[Kappa][t_] = 5.4*10^\[Minus]3 t



dConductance[t_] = 
  2  2  \[Kappa][
    t] copperwidth 1./(dielectricthickness - copperthickness)/2;


sol = NDSolve[{D[D[Tc[x], x], x] - 
     137. dConductance[Tc[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, 
   D[Tg[x] D[Tg[x], x], x] + 
     137. dConductance[Tg[x]] (Tc[x] - Tg[x]) == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[{Tg[x] == 300, Tc[x] == 300}, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[Tg[x] == 30, x == 1]}, {Tc, Tg}, {x} \[Element] 
   Line[{{0}, {1}}], InitialSeeding -> {Tg[x] == 300, Tc[x] == 300}];
```

Visualization

```
    Plot[Evaluate[{Tg[x], Tc[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Tg", "Tc"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: This looks right - thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @HM51 You are welcome!